# Mention of Saraswathi river in Buddhist scriptures

Tags: reference-request, hinduism

Does any authentic Buddhist scripture mentions the Saraswathi River? If yes where and what does it say?

Saraswathi river is an ancient Indian river mentioned widely across all Indian scriptures but it's dating is debated. We know that Buddha lived around 6th century BC, if Saraswathi river is mentioned then we can be of some certainty that the river flowed, however sparsely around 6th century BC.

[Refer](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25210364)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the following references to the Sarasvati River in the Pali Canon:

> Now at that time the brahmin Sundarika Bhāradvāja was sitting not far
> from the Buddha. He said to the Buddha, “But does Master Gotama go to
> the river Bāhuka to bathe?”
>
> “Brahmin, why go to the river Bāhuka? What can the river Bāhuka do?”
>
> “Many people agree that the river Bāhuka bestows cleanliness and
> merit. And many people wash off their bad deeds in the river Bāhuka.”
>
> Then the Buddha addressed Sundarika in verse:
>
> The Bāhuka and the Adhikakka,
> the Gaya and the Sundarika too,
> Sarasvatī and Payāga,
> and the river Bāhumati:
> a fool can constantly plunge into them
> but it won’t purify their dark deeds.
>
> What can the Sundarika do?
> What the Payāga or the Bāhuka?
> They can’t cleanse a cruel and criminal person
> from their bad deeds.
>
> For the pure in heart it’s always
> the spring festival or the sabbath.
> For the pure in heart and clean of deed,
> their vows will always be fulfilled.
> It’s here alone that you should bathe, brahmin,
> making yourself a sanctuary for all creatures.
>
> And if you speak no lies,
> nor harm any living creature,
> nor steal anything not given,
> and you’re faithful and not stingy:
> what’s the point of going to Gaya?
> For any well may be your Gaya!”
> [Majjhima Nikaya 7](https://suttacentral.net/mn7/en/sujato)

> Oh, when will I cross the Ganges, Yamunā,
> and Sarasvatī rivers, the Pātāla country,
> and the dangerous Baḷavāmukha sea,
> by psychic power unimpeded? When will it be?
> [Theragatha 19.1](https://suttacentral.net/thag19.1/en/sujato)

> And again, O king, just as there are five hundred rivers which flow
> down from the Himālayas, but of these ten only are reckoned in
> enumerations of rivers—the Ganges, the Jumna, the Aciravatī, the
> Sarabhū, the Mahī, the Indus, the Sarasvatī, the Vetravatī, the
> Vītaṁsā, and the Candabhāgā—the others not being included in the
> catalogue because of their intermittent flow of water.
> [Milindapanha 5.1.4](https://suttacentral.net/mil5.1.4/en/tw_rhysdavids)

> The Indus, and the Sarasvatī
> are rivers, like the Candabhāgā,
> the Ganges and the Yamuna
> the Sarabhu and the Mahī too.
> [Thera Apadana 3](https://suttacentral.net/tha-ap3/en/walters)

There's another mention of this river in this Chinese Mahayana Sutra:

> Nāgasena asked the king, “Would those who have never seen the great
> ocean, know that the ocean is great? There are five great rivers, and
> to each of them, there are also five hundred small tributaries. The
> five great rivers are: (1) the Ganges, (2) the Sindhu, (3) the Sita,
> (4) the Oxus and (5) the Sarasvati. The waters of these five great
> rivers flow to the ocean day and night, but the water in the ocean
> neither increases nor decreases.”
> [T 1670B Nāgasena Bhikṣu Sūtra 2.46](https://suttacentral.net/t1670b2.46/en/guang)